# TYPO3: <f:cObject /> is not working with variable from Typo3 Extension?

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

My TYPO3 4.7.17 extension has the following code:
(Controller)

```
public function listJobPublicAction(Tx_Htmjob10_Domain_Model_JobDemand $jobDemand = NULL) {
    $nrAllJobs = $this->jobRepository->countAll();
    ...
    $this->view->assign('jobs', $jobs);
}
```

and my extension view:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.count2">{nrAllJobs}</f:cObject>
```

my TYPOScript:

```
lib.count2= HTML
lib.count2{
    value.current = 1
    value.wrap = <strong>|</strong>
}
```

This is working fine with **Fluid template  in TYPO3 extension**

I want to use nrAllJobs in **Fluid partial**, but  is not working. This is an empty line.

```
<f:layout name="Default" />
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.count2">{nrAllJobs}</f:cObject>
```

How to access PHP variable from Fluid partial (not **Fluid template  in TYPO3 extension**)?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Why don't you just pass $nrAllJobs to the Fluid view, then pass it to the Fluid partial, use it in the partial and forget the whole TypoScript stuff?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm trying to access $nrAllJobs from my Fluid partial.

The following line only display in my extension View
`<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.count2">{nrAllJobs}</f:cObject>`

I have used Templavoila, it's working fine.

Comment: You can view my site: [link](http://sgd01.vitransportal.com/index.php?id=131&L=2)

I want to show value in line _"The total number of offers job: 4"_ in extension **Transport jobs** to Footer Partial **There are on the platform**. <f:cObject /> only working in my extension.

Answer (score 1):

To pass a value to a TyposcriptObject for, you did it right:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.count2">{nrAllJobs}</f:cObject>
```

As you mentioned this is working in Fluidtemplate but not in Partial. One quick guess: Did you pass your variable from your template to your partial? Like this:

```
<f:render partial="MyPartial" arguments="{_all}" />
```

Notice that `arguments` needs to be an array or the keyword `_all`, wich simply passes all varibales to the partial. If you just want to pass your variable, use `{nrAllJobs:nrAllJobs}` If you pass yout variable to your partial, there is no difference whether you use the f:cObject ViewHelper in a template or a partial.

But, as mentioned by others here, you can display the value of your variable without the detour over a TypoScript object. Just do `{nrAllJobs}` but still make sure you passed your variable to your patial.

Comment: Who ever have the problem above I bet the problem is the forgotten arguments in the render partial thing. This actually answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the cObject function works like that.
It is:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.myObject"></f:cObject>
```

so your variable is the lib.myObject here.

Maybe you try:

```
<strong>{nrAllJobs}</strong>
```

Within the fluid template.